# how to delete compute engine vm using terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have a temporary VM created in GCP using terraform google_compute_instance module.. this VM has a startup script that will execute a bunch of activities.. at the very end of the script there is a `gcloud compute instances delete` command.. this is effectively tearing itself down..

1. I am wondering if the deletion of VM should be done outside of the startup script..
2. I need a way to test if the VM has been deleted ? perhaps in terratest or some other testing framework..

Can someone please help..?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have other resources in your terraform configuration, you can just run destroy command after applying the conf.

```
terraform apply && terraform destroy
```

In the other hand, if your configuration manages some resources and you just want one to be deleted at the end, you can target the instance to delete, but this approach does not look really solid.

```
terraform apply && terraform destroy -target google_compute_instance.instance
```

Comment: What kind of bunch activities performs the startup script ? Could it be performed from your workstation instead ? If yes, you can use local-exec and null resource with explicit dependencies using depends_on keyword.